# What is an "avenger advertisement" coming from the locationd process?

Tags: macos, console

Out of boredom, I ran the console application that comes with macOS by default.  As I was looking through some of the logs, I noticed a line that said:

`"msg":"onAvengerAdvertisementDetected: got avenger advertisement", "subHarvester":"Avenger"}`

coming from the subsystem `com.apple.locationd.Core` under the category `Harvester`.  After looking further, I noticed a bunch of other calls using the term "advertisement" in them too.  For example, there's:

`{"msg":"convertToSPAdvertisement", "address":<private>, "data":<private>, "date":<private>, "rssi":<private>, "status":<private>, "reserved":<private>, "subHarvester":"Avenger"}`

coming from the same subsystem and category.

Does anyone have any idea where these logs are coming from?

I'm on a MacBook Air M1 running macOS Monterrey 12.2.1

Comment: Can you add the full line you see in the log, and also name the log file you found them in?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Very curious to find out from which app this originates. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I can see this same console log message appear whenever I enable (in system preferences) location services for any app that asks for it. The message appeared even after I entirely wiped my computer and reinstalled the OS. By turning off location services for every app (except core system tools), I stopped seeing the message.

This whole investigation began because Google Chrome started constantly freezing on a brand new Macbook Pro.